How does one accurately measure electrical power transferred outside and along a conducting wire pair?
Note:
I edited the below after a discussion with a high profile PSE contributor as I realized that while dielectrics always interact with E&M, the power transfer I originally proposed at 60 hz is way too low for the below to be a worthwhile experiment at this frequency. I'd need to conduct the same experiment at much higher frequencies for the most common insulation/dielectric and this would introduce many complications. I'm still searching for other ideas.
Many claim that near light-speed electrical power from a household outlet does not travel to an appliance within the copper of a wire pair. This implies that more than 6000 W of AC electromagnetic power travels from my outlet to my jacuzzi along the outside and through the insulation around the copper only.
Can I confirm this?
I don't have big ideas only musings, and none of them appropriate for my jacuzzi related question. That was intended to start the conversation and also to see if anyone had thoughts on it. So moving on to non-jacuzzi related musings. One such musing is as follows:
I'm curious if there exists  insulation that heats measurably at low frequency (e.g. below 100khz) and very high power such that if
insulating an appropriate gauge wire pair it might be possible to measure temperature changes of the insulation itself given that the copper will not experience noticeable heating relative to the insulation.
Ex.
If I found such an insulation that heated at 100khz, a 10 ft 16 AWG wire pair should be adequate for this thought experiment. Overkill actually, but this is the idea: relatively little measurable heating of the copper at this frequency even at 'large power'. What 'large power' is for this experiment I admit I haven't researched yet, but if such an insulation exists it shouldn't be hard to determine. I'll refer to it as Pexp which always less than Pmax meaning the largest power at 100hz such that the insulation is ensured to not melt or outgas or degrade in any way.
As I change Pexp such that Pexp < Pmax I would expect a predictable change in temperature of the insulation to allow me to confirm that all the power is or is not transferred outside the copper only.
This is only a thought experiment as I realize the dangers of attempting such a thing. Clearly one problem with the above is that any heating of the insulation will result in heating of the copper, but I believe this can be accounted for. Another problem at the powers I'm assuming would be the power source which would likely overheat and/or be very expensive. Yet another might involve radiative losses for the large power transfer being considered.
Just off the top of my head I think 500W at 100khz would be high enough to cause issues. I can't imagine what power source could reliably generate such a power at this frequency. Maybe people have experience with this kind of thing and can give input.
Regardless the above is just one such musing. Can someone suggest a better way to measure power transferred outside the copper only given the problem as stated atop this question? While there are many ways to determine total power transfer of the wire pair, I know none that determine the power transfer outside the copper only.
If anyone can suggest an improvement to this question please do. This is my first contribution to PSE in years and I'm concerned about being downvoted because of some impropriety. Thank you.

Even supposing that the energy really is transported by the field surrounding the conductor, why do you suppose that the insulation would interact with the field and absorb energy from it?

dielectrics always interact with E&M, and I assumed that at high enough power there must be heating. but after discussion with Rennie below I realized 60 hz is too  low a freq for this to be a worthwhile endeavor. I'd need to conduct the same experiment at much higher frequencies which  would introduce many complications. I'm still searching for other ideas, but need to edit my question. thanks.

@SolomonSlow This is not a supposition but a consequence of the present theory. See FL2, ch 27.6.

This won't work because you would be measuring the power dissipated not the power being transferred. You are quite correct the fields around the wire are an essential part of the energy transport process, but the power dissipated in the wire is lost as heat due to collisions of conduction electrons with nuclei in the conductor. This happens in the conductor so it's the wire that gets hot not the insulation.
You could demonstrate how energy can be lost by winding a coil around your conductor then connecting the coil to a resistor. This would basically be a transformer with the wire as a primary and the coil + resistor as the secondary, and now power will be dissipated as the EMF induced in the coil creates a current through the resistor.
You should not regard the way the fields around the wire are involved in energy transport as somehow mystical. This is exactly how transformers work, and there are probably many transformers around you as you read this. Assuming the question was inspired by the Veritasium video, you should note that the circuit used in that video lights the lightbulb after a time $1/c$ because it is acting as a (rather inefficient) transformer.

This surprises me John. So you believe a 6 AWG wire at this short length will heat significantly? I was trying to choose a gauge that wouldn't for this experiment. Should I change this to 2 AWG then? I do realize that's an enormous diameter.

@hazyjz what I'm saying is that any energy lost will be lost in the conductor since  there are no mechanisms by which energy can be lost in the insulation. As you say, with a large wire the amount of energy lost will be tiny anyway. If you make the insulator a partial conductor then you will start seeing some energy lost in the insulator, but of course then it is no longer an insulator.

Also just to be clear, I am not trying to prove there is no power transfer outside the conductor. I am trying to prove that the entirety of the 66,000 W is transferred outside the copper. The idea has been on my mind long before Veritasium. I have noted that JD Jackson, Hayt et al all mention but neglect a very small axial power transfer within perfect conducting media where skin effect is large. However I don't want to go into the details here as that is another topic.

dielectrics will heat when power transferred through them is extreme enough. this was my motivation here, albeit without providing specific details about the dielectric. I understand transformers well and realized long ago this won't prove anything specific about power transfer outside the insulation itself. I also realize who you are and want to be careful to not cross a line here. am i incorrect that a dielectric will heat significantly at some extreme power? regardless thank you for your thoughts here. Much appreciated!

Dielectrics will heat in an (oscillating) electric field if their dielectric constant is large. However insulators are chosen to have a very low dielectric constant for the rather obvious reason that hot insulation is rarely a good thing when wiring a building. My example of wrapping the wire in a coil is effectively the limit of $k\to\infty$. You don't have to worry about my high rep, I can and have posted answers that were completely wrong (hopefully I have now found and deleted most of them :-).

ahhh! I just realized that 60hz is too low a frequency for dialectric heating. maybe I should change my question so that it involves a much higher frequency. of course everything else changes with the idea of a perfect conductor.

the transformer will change the electrical circuit significantly. I'd prefer to keep musing on this topic with the circuit as is.

thanks John. I've always wanted to contact you about many other topics. specifically you and annav  appear to align well with my understanding of QM. Maybe we cross paths on a different question later.

You are always welcome to ask questions in the Physics SE chat room :-)

I do have much higher level questions directly related to Jackson's treatment of perfect conductors. He has left out quite a bit as related to this topic in particular. I may review Zangwill soon and start a chat. Thanks again.

I have modified my question. Just want to notify you in case you think I've done something inappropriate for PSE's tastes and/or if you want to respond somehow.

It is incorrect to suggest that the transfer of energy from outside the wire has anything to do with induction. Faraday’s law is not involved, as E and B are static.

my2cts that comment requires an explanation as I'm sure you're aware. it also requires that specific details of the circuit are mentioned.

It is true that the present theory implies that the power is not transferred through the wire but by the fields outside the wire. This ‘intuitively screwy’ (Feyman’s words, only in the audio tape) is discussed in FL2, ch 27.6. This is a consequence of the requirement that energy and energy transport densities must be expressed in the fields E and B, that is, must be gauge invariant.
I have proposed, as an alternative, the Wave Theory that among its many advantages has the power transferred through the wire. Watch my 26 minute video at https://youtu.be/eCruJN3w-CY?si=WVADJVHR0phUwX2q.

This question is specifically about experimentation for testing theories. My interest begins with JD Jackson and Hayt and Balanis. The latter two showed a non-zero Poynting Vector within perfect conductors - TEM and axial flow - but neglected it entirely without comment. Jackson also showed this component and footnoted with no further exposition. My observations: 1. treatments are for perfect conductors w large skin depth. 2. treatments are for steady state AC and don't treat with precision the process leading from 0 voltage differential & 0 power transfer to steady state power transfer.

How strong magnetic field energy is established within conductors is key. this energy accounts for most of the energy within a perfect conductor carrying AC current which is in phase with voltage difference between the wire pair. my interest relates to how such current stays in phase within the conductor (i.e. not just near the surface) if there is no near light speed TEM within. My opinion is that there is TEM at light speed within but extremely weak because almost all power is immediately absorbed to keep current in phase. This may be treated in Zangwill.

if you will propose a method of experimentation then I will upvote your answer. if you don't have such a method I can ask another question and notify you .

@hazyj There is no electrodynamic way to directly measure the difference between the two descriptions. Both descriptions agree with the Maxwell equations. However the gauge theoretical description is strongly counterintuitive. It leads physicists astray and provokes questions such as the one that you posted. Obviously, the Drude model gives a much better account of conduction than the gauge theory.
The only way to measure the distributions of energy and energy transport would be by gravitation. However, such effects are incredibly small and unlikely to ever be experimentally accessible.

then I cannot upvote your answer anton although what you've posited is clearly interesting. I do have my suspicions however, because I'm convinced that one must treat power transfer and absorption within the conductor quantum mechanically. the TEM exists within and its energy propagates axially at light speed. extremely weak which is what would be expected, but the absorption is what keeps the changing magnetic wavefront inside in phase with voltage difference between conductors.

" It leads physicists astray and provokes questions such as the one that you posted." this is a bit heavy handed. this is not my theory nor would being led astray lead to my question nor understanding. you are putting forth a lot of theory and claiming that it's almost impossible to prove. I'm not sure about the relevance here.

@hazyjz A TEM is a radiative mode. The problem here is quasi static. There is no wave and no wavefront, unless you want to consider radiative losses. You are then entering the subject of low frequency radio (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longwave). The QM model that describes the conduction in the wire is the free electron model, aka Drude-Sommerfeld model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model).

correction. there is a radiative mode TEM within and extremely weak. please re-read my points which you appear to be glossing over.

a TEM mode can exist and be continuously absorbed. you appear to be referring to sustained TEM in waveguides with no loss.

@hazyjz My answer addresses this statement: 'Many claim that near light-speed electrical power from a household outlet does not travel to an appliance within the copper of a wire pair. This implies that more than 6000 W of AC electromagnetic power travels from my outlet to my jacuzzi along the outside and through the insulation around the copper only.' This statement flies against any intuition considering electrical conduction, including the intuition at the basis of the Drude-Sommerfeld model. Yet this statement is correct according to the standard theory. Check out FL2, ch. 27.6.

@hazyjz 'there is a radiative mode TEM within' No there is not. The wavelength of 100 kHz inside copper is 2-3 km. Question: are you really reading your jacuzzi with 100 kHz and not with 100 Hz?

we are now off topic. I might start a new topic instead. zangwill has treated much of our theoretical discussion here.  carriers move. carriers accelerate. transverse EM exists and is absorbed. there is relaxation and there is shielding.  none of it 100% effective. current must be in phase with voltage difference between conductors. we know this. we measure this, just like we know that before a conducting plate reaches steady state voltage difference across its faces there is a non-zero field inside. that is radiative and moves charges which absorb the radiative energy.

FYI - i moved from the jacuzzi visualization to the musings. they are separate. I will edit to make this more clear.

regardless you need to get through Jackson again to understand his treatment which is where my end of our discussion began. I believe chapters 6 and 7 and note his mention of the transverse mode. I have no idea why you mention the wavelength. it is the same outside and in the insulation. 2-3 km.
